# Datanode not starting in cloudera pseudo distributed mode using YARN

Tags: apache, hadoop, ubuntu-14.04

I installed cloudera hadoop(YARN) in pseudo distributed mode in Ubuntu 14.04 using this tutorial:
 http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/enterprise/5-3-x/topics/cdh_qs_yarn_pseudo.html
 However when I am starting the services my datanode fails to start. I had previously installed Mvr1 and then everything was fine so nothing should have gone wrong with the prerequisites required for this installation. I uninstalled all versions of hadoop using sudo apt-get purge and then freshly installed it but with no use.
 Datanode log entry is : 
                                    >2015-11-14 09:54:34,292 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting

> 2015-11-14 09:54:35,363 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 0 time(s); >retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
>   2015-11-14 09:54:36,364 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 1 time(s); >retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
>   2015-11-14 09:54:37,365 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 2 time(s); >retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
>   2015-11-14 09:54:38,365 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 3 time(s); >retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
>   2015-11-14 09:54:39,366 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 4 time(s); >retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
>   2015-11-14 09:54:40,366 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 5 time(s); >retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
>   2015-11-14 09:54:41,367 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 6 time(s); >retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
>   2015-11-14 09:54:42,367 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 7 time(s); >retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
>   2015-11-14 09:54:43,368 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 8 time(s); >retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
>   2015-11-14 09:54:44,368 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 9 time(s); >retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
>   2015-11-14 09:54:44,370 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Problem connecting to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020
>   2015-11-14 09:54:49,792 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Lock on /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/hdfs/dfs/data/in_use.lock >acquired by nodename 1088@monamie-VPCEG3AEN
>   2015-11-14 09:54:49,795 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: java.io.IOException: Incompatible clusterIDs in /var/lib/hadoop->hdfs/cache/hdfs/dfs/data: namenode clusterID = CID-21fe9d61-d016-43e8-b5fb-1b43851c2ffa; datanode clusterID = CID-2f6844e6-c348-4a40->ac2b-8ef08c674081
>   2015-11-14 09:54:49,796 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Initialization failed for Block pool  (Datanode >Uuid unassigned) service to localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Exiting. 
>   java.io.IOException: All specified directories are failed to load.
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.recoverTransitionRead(DataStorage.java:479)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initStorage(DataNode.java:1398)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initBlockPool(DataNode.java:1363)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPOfferService.verifyAndSetNamespaceInfo(BPOfferService.java:317)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.connectToNNAndHandshake(BPServiceActor.java:228)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.run(BPServiceActor.java:847)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   2015-11-14 09:54:49,798 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Ending block pool service for: Block pool  >>>(Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to localhost/127.0.0.1:8020
>   2015-11-14 09:54:49,904 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Removed Block pool  (Datanode Uuid unassigned)
>   2015-11-14 09:54:51,904 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Exiting Datanode
>   2015-11-14 09:54:51,905 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 0 
>  *********Noteworthy line is : >Problem connecting to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020 ******** 
>          Please help me recognize what might have gone wrong.   
>  
>  Namenode log entry: 
> >2015-11-14 10:38:51,230 WARN org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hdfs (auth:SIMPLE) >cause:java.io.IOException: File /user/oozie/share/lib/mapreduce-streaming/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0-cdh5.4.8.jar.*COPYING* could only be >replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
>   2015-11-14 10:38:51,231 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 3 on 8020, call >org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol.addBlock from 127.0.0.1:45057 Call#5 Retry#0
>   java.io.IOException: File /user/oozie/share/lib/mapreduce-streaming/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0-cdh5.4.8.jar.*COPYING* could only be replicated to >0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1541)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3289)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:668)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.addBlock>>>>>(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:212)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock>(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:483)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod>(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1060)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2044)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2040)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2038)
>   2015-11-14 10:38:51,320 WARN org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hdfs (auth:SIMPLE) >cause:java.io.IOException: File /user/oozie/share/lib/mapreduce-streaming/hadoop-streaming.jar.*COPYING* could only be replicated to 0 nodes >instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
>   2015-11-14 10:38:51,320 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 9 on 8020, call >org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol.addBlock from 127.0.0.1:45057 Call#12 Retry#0
>   java.io.IOException: File /user/oozie/share/lib/mapreduce-streaming/hadoop-streaming.jar.*COPYING* could only be replicated to 0 nodes >instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1541)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3289)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:668)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.addBlock>(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:212)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock>(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:483)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod>(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1060)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2044)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2040)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2038)

Comment: datanode is not able to connect to namenode, is your namenode up?

Comment: When I checked the status of services I found my namenode and resourcemanager dead. Datanode and all other services are running as shown in the status. I have attached the namenode log in the original question. Please help me identify what may have gone wrong. I have followed all steps of the cloudera tutorial(link given) exactly. Can you tell me if any additional configuration are required in YARN ?

Comment: have you formatted namenode?

Comment: Even I faced the same issue. Any updates ?